# Why does type double PI = 22/7 returns 3, but double PI = 22.0/7 or 22/7.0 returns correct result 3.14..?

Tags: java

I tried of finding answer by googling as well as debugging variable behavior, but unfortunately I dint find any proper answer. Its a question related to Java for instance.

- Question :
  Why 'double' type variable behaves like 'int' type in below condition :

double PI = 22/7 which returns 3

but, double PI = 22.0/7 or 22/7.0 returns 3.14xxxxxxx ?

Help appreciated...Thanks.

Comment: Look up `integer arithmetic` and `binary numeric promotion`. Also, nowhere in that question does a `double` behave as an `int`.

Comment: Because in arithmetic operations output gives the result in terms of highest data type among all involved variables or constants(Applied only on primitive data types)

Comment: @Shailesh Saxena : Thanks. I missed this important concept.

Comment: @user3580294 : Yes, I would have checked these concepts before raising question here. Well... much appreciated of you guys answered so quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in java arithmetic operations output gives the result in terms of highest data type among all involved variables or constants(Applied only on primitive data types).

For example if in any arithmetic operation like below:

1. Scenario 1=> var1 is int, var 2 is float, var3 is double: You will get result in double
2. Scenario 2=> var1 is short, var2 is long and var3 is float: you will get result in float
3. Scenario 3=> var1 is int, var2 is long, var3 is double: you will get result in double

Note: float family data type(float & double) always dominate to int family data types even both have same size, like in case of long and float output will be in float.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's how Java (and some other programming languages) have been implemented.

Since both are integers, the expected result will be an integer as well:

```
int/int = int
```

In the other hand, when one operator is `double`, the result will also be `double`

```
double/int = double
int/double = double
```

Comment: Thanks. Well Explained.

Answer (score 2):

Because by default in java numerals are integer data type, so, when you are doing numeric operation with integers, the result also will be integer. When you assign that integer to a double variable, it is promoted to a double, but its value is kept. So you end up with a double with the exact same value as the result integer -- in this case, `3.0`.

In your first case, both are integers, so the result also an integer, and you have assigned to double. But the conversion(integer to double) happened before assignment to double.

In the second or third case, one in double, so the operation done on double, So the result also a double value.

Comment: "So, the decimal values are converted to integer." Huh? Where does that happen?

Comment: I know what you're trying to say, but I think the wording is still misleading. What happens is the integer value is converted to a double, so because the integer value is 3, the double value is also 3. Doubles can't be converted to integers without an explicit cast.

Comment: @user3580294 : Yes, If you can edit my answer with proper wordings. Bit busy with some tasks

Comment: OK, gave it a shot. What do you think?

Comment: @Abimaran Kugathasan : Thanks... I understood the concept lies beside.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 22 / 7; // same as double d = (int)22 / (int) 7 
    System.out.println(d);  // so prints 3.0
    double dd = 22.0/7;  // same as double dd = (double)22 / (int) 7 
    System.out.println(dd);//prints 3.14xxxx
}
```

Comment: @downvoters.. seriously.. Whats wrong with my answer?

Comment: Its absolutely correct seems to me. And the very concept i missed so I raised here. Thanks guys for helping so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Or 'Pi= 22D / 7D' does it too. Here 22 and 7 are declared as 'double', not 'int'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick answer.