# Why I can not see the double value in a textView

Tags: android

Why I can not see the double value in a `textView`?

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

double x = 5/2;

textView.setText(String.valueOf(x)); // I see this result as 2.0 and not as the 2.5
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554032/how-to-get-the-full-fraction-value-of-a-division-result-in-java?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198620/why-variable-type-double-pi-22-7-returns-3-but-double-pi-22-0-7-or-22-7-0-r?lq=1

Comment: (You will also want to format the number correctly or else you will run into 'odd cases'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing `2.0` because `5/2` is integer division. Change the line to `double x = 5.0/2;` or similar.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java) for more.

Answer (score 4):

**In Android TextView, you can use in that way,**
Use Double.toString:

```
result = number1/number2    
String stringdouble= Double.toString(result);
textview1.setText(stringdouble));
```

or you can use the NumberFormat:

```
Double result = number1/number2;
NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
textview1.setText(nm.format(result));
```

To force for 3 units precision:

```
private static DecimalFormat REAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
textview1.setText(REAL_FORMATTER.format(result));
```

Comment: This misses out on the problem of `number1/number2` (where the numbers are both integers), but it does show how to *format a number for display* ..

Answer (score 2):

This should work `double x = ((double) 5) /2.`